# How to build ELF on MacOS using LLVM?

Tags: macos, clang, llvm, elf, lld

I am trying to build ELF-file using **LLVM** (from **Homebrew**) but I can't get how to link it.

My files:
**multiboot2.h**:

```
struct multiboot2_header_t {
// Stub
} multiboot2_header __attribute__((section(".multiboot")));
```

**kernel.c**:

```
#include "multiboot2.h"

void _start() {
// Stub
}
```

**linker.ld**:

```
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    .text: {
    /* link the multiboot struct here */
    . = ALIGN(8);
    KEEP(*(.multiboot))
    /* place all of your code afterwards */
    *(.text)
    }
}
```

I can compile it to object file **kernel.o** by command `clang -c -o kernel.o kernel.c --target x86_64-none-gnu` but I can't get how to link this object file using my linker script.

**P.S.** Before I never worked with **LLVM** and **linker** directly, only **GNU GCC** building simple Linux apps.

Comment: When you say "build ELF-file" on macOS, what are you really trying to do?  Macs don't use ELF — they use their own object file format, and ELF-related tools are not much use, therefore.  You won't be able to run an ELF-file on macOS (unless you revise the kernel process management code extensively) and you won't have any ELF support libraries (system library, etc — let alone `libelf.dylib`).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I know I can launch it on mac, I wanna run it on qemu via grub loader

Comment: OK — well, good luck.  I'm not convinced, but you know and I don't so I bow to your greater knowledge.

Comment: You obviously need a linker that can produce an ELF file. Are you using such linker? Which linker is that, and what is the actual command line you used?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I built ELF already (but object file only) and found how to pass linker script to clang but now it fails with my linker script. I will put more detail in my question when I will have access to my macbook

Comment: @EmployedRussian sorry, I will post a bit later, I am away form macbook now, unfortunately

Comment: @EmployedRussian but you are right the problem is with llvm-ld linker, it can't understand my linker.ld script (fails at `.text: {`)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60245812/816536 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/59811705/816536 both seem related -- and do not yet have an answer either.  The docs suggest linker script support is not yet complete in LLD.  Perhaps you can post your linker command line too?

Comment: Just so everybody knows, LLVM is a cross compiler in and of itself. What OP is asking is doable on any platform, and is a primary use case of clang. The answer below is correct if memory serves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
clang --target=aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu -c file.c
```

Clang will see that you are targeting Linux and emit an ELF file.o

```
% file file.o
file.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

You'll then want to use *ld.lld* which you can get from Homebrew. BTW, linker script support for ELF *ld.lld* is quite good. However, linker script support for Mach-O *ld64.lld* is non-existent.